# How to write the values to another column of dataframe based on Row_id column and value exist in match column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this which is having **ROW_ID** and **Matches** columns. Based on the value in each row of **Matches** column I should write in **Result** column. For example, in first row, we have **; ALL MATCH -3**, so in the new column **Result**, this **; ALL MATCH** should be present in **ROW_ID** 3. In 8th **ROW_ID**, we have **; ALL MATCH -9; Diff in# -10**. So in our **Result** column **; ALL MATCH** should be present in **ROW_ID** 9 and **; Diff in#** should be present in **ROW_ID** 10

| ROW_ID | Matches |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ; ALL MATCH -3 |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 4 |  |
| 5 | ; ALL MATCH -6 |
| 6 |  |
| 7 |  |
| 8 | ; ALL MATCH -9; Diff in# -10 |
| 9 |  |
| 10 |  |

That means the final dataframe should be like this.

| ROW_ID | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 | ; ALL MATCH |
| 4 |  |
| 5 |  |
| 6 | ; ALL MATCH |
| 7 |  |
| 8 |  |
| 9 | ; ALL MATCH |
| 10 | ; Diff in# |

I tried a lot, I extracted the int value seperately and other parts separately for each row using dataframe.iterrows(). But I am not able to print that value to a particular position. df.at[] method won't work. loc and iloc also i tried, but not getting how can i print that string to particular row of that column.

Comment: Is this your most complex case? Can you have elements other than empty or starting with  "; ALL MATCH"? Other columns? etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['Result'] = df['ROW_ID'].map(
    df['Matches'].str.extractall('(; [^-]+) -(\d+)')
                 .astype({1: int}).set_index(1).squeeze()
).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   ROW_ID                       Matches       Result
0       1                ; ALL MATCH -3             
1       2                                           
2       3                                ; ALL MATCH
3       4                                           
4       5                ; ALL MATCH -6             
5       6                                ; ALL MATCH
6       7                                           
7       8  ; ALL MATCH -9; Diff in# -10             
8       9                                ; ALL MATCH
9      10                                 ; Diff in#

# Details about extractall
>>> df['Matches'].str.extractall('(; [^-]+) -(\d+)')
                   0   1
  match                 
0 0      ; ALL MATCH   3
4 0      ; ALL MATCH   6
7 0      ; ALL MATCH   9
  1       ; Diff in#  10
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary DataFrame as:

```
wrk = df.Matches.str.extractall(r'(?P<Result>;\D+)-(?P<id>\d+)')
```

Then strip the trailing spaces from *Result* column:

```
wrk.Result = wrk.Result.str.strip()
```

The next step is to change the type of *id* column to *int*, as so
far it is of *object* type (actually a *string*):

```
wrk.id = wrk.id.astype('int64')
```

and set it as the index:

```
wrk.set_index('id', inplace=True)
```

Now *wrk* is actually a *Series*, containing:

```
         Result
id             
3   ; ALL MATCH
6   ; ALL MATCH
9   ; ALL MATCH
10   ; Diff in#
```

Then, to generate the result, run:

```
res = df.merge(wrk, how='left', left_on='ROW_ID', right_index=True)
```

The result is:

```
   ROW_ID                       Matches       Result
0       1                ; ALL MATCH -3          NaN
1       2                           NaN          NaN
2       3                           NaN  ; ALL MATCH
3       4                           NaN          NaN
4       5                ; ALL MATCH -6          NaN
5       6                           NaN  ; ALL MATCH
6       7                           NaN          NaN
7       8  ; ALL MATCH -9; Diff in# -10          NaN
8       9                           NaN  ; ALL MATCH
9      10                           NaN   ; Diff in#
```

If you don't want "NaN" in "not filled" fields, append `.fillna('')`
to the last instruction.